# Img ordering with html and dropdown menu html css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a image go on top of the background image and both of those underneath the drop down menu.
(ALL IMAGES FOR THIS QUESTIONS ARE FROM GOOGLE SO U CAN SEE)

So in order [TOP TO BOTTOM]

Drop Down

Motorbike

Background

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated :D <3

```css
/* Drop Down Menu */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navClass {
 padding-right: 5px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; right: 0;
}

.right {
 float: right;
}

.navClass > ul {
 background-color: #5E5D5D;
 color: #D8D8D8;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.navClass > ul > li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px 25px;
 position: relative;
}

.navClass > ul > li:hover {
 background-color: #383838;
}

ul.sub-menu {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #383838;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 125px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 padding-left: 0pc;
 margin-left: -25px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 opacity: 0;
}

ul.sub-menu li {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.navClass li:hover .sub-menu {
 opacity: 1;
 background-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.navClass ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #D8D8D8;
}

.sub-menu li:hover {
 background-color: #383838;
}

/* Background */

/* ZeeFro */
.zeefro {   
 z-index: -1;
 text-align: center;
}   

/* Background */

.bg-main {   
 z-index: -2;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>ZeFrolity</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="zeefro">
<img src="http://ambebajaj.com/app/webroot/img/uploads/Homeslider/1458125292bikeprod-img.png" width="100%" height="100%">
</nav>

<nav class="bg-Main">
<img src="http://www.suttontrust.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Coding.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</nav>

<nav class="navClass">

<ul>

 <li><a href="">Contact Me</li></a>

 <li><a href="">Home</li></a>
 <li><a href="">About Me</li></a>
 <li><a href="">Portfolio

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="">Logos</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Banners</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Twitch</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Youtube</li></a>
 </ul>

 </li>

 <li><a href="">Shop

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="">Graphics</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Merch</li></a>
 </ul>

 </li>

 <li><a href="">Social Media

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="">Twitch</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Youtube</li></a>
  <li><a href="">All</li></a>
 </ul>

 </li>
 
</ul>

</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

I thought z-index 1,2 and 3 would work cause they work like layers but they didn't if anyone knows the issue please let me know :D

As you can see the png img (the motorbike is on top of the page) and the tech jpg img is underneath it , i want the background of the motorbike to be the tech pretty much

Kind regards

Zefrolity

Comment: I'm confused. Your snippet appears to be exhibiting the behaviour that you're asking for. Could you clarify?

Comment: as you can see the png img (the motorbike is on top of the page) and the tech jpg img is underneath it , i want the background of the motorbike to be the tech pretty much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Negative z-index doesn't really work, but you can achieve the desired effect with some minimal reordering.

```css
/* Drop Down Menu */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navClass {
    z-index: 3;
 padding-right: 5px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; right: 0;
}

.right {
 float: right;
}

.navClass > ul {
 background-color: #5E5D5D;
 color: #D8D8D8;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.navClass > ul > li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px 25px;
 position: relative;
}

.navClass > ul > li:hover {
 background-color: #383838;
}

ul.sub-menu {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #383838;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 125px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 padding-left: 0pc;
 margin-left: -25px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 opacity: 0;
}

ul.sub-menu li {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.navClass li:hover .sub-menu {
 opacity: 1;
 background-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.navClass ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #D8D8D8;
}

.sub-menu li:hover {
 background-color: #383838;
}

/* Background */

/* ZeeFro */
.zeefro {
    position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 text-align: center;
}   

/* Background */

.bg-main {
    position:absolute;   
 z-index: 1;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>ZeFrolity</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>



<nav class="navClass">

<ul>

 <li><a href="">Contact Me</li></a>

 <li><a href="">Home</li></a>
 <li><a href="">About Me</li></a>
 <li><a href="">Portfolio

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="">Logos</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Banners</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Twitch</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Youtube</li></a>
 </ul>

 </li>

 <li><a href="">Shop

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="">Graphics</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Merch</li></a>
 </ul>

 </li>

 <li><a href="">Social Media

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="">Twitch</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Youtube</li></a>
  <li><a href="">All</li></a>
 </ul>

 </li>
 
</ul>

</nav>

<nav class="zeefro">
<img src="http://ambebajaj.com/app/webroot/img/uploads/Homeslider/1458125292bikeprod-img.png" width="100%" height="100%">
</nav>

<nav class="bg-Main">
<img src="http://www.suttontrust.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Coding.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nah that does work with the 2 images but i want them behind the drop down menu also so its a full screen effect

Comment: @zefrolity - just updated it. Pretty sure that's what you're looking for, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: AWESOME THANK YOU it means alot :D

Comment: @zefrolity np. Though I wouldn't say no to an upvote / accepted answer ;)

Comment: oh i normally do tht straight away i forgot sorry!

Comment: @zefrolity no worries!